# How to convert variable from char**& to char*& in a safe way?

Tags: c++

In my cpp project, for some reasons, I have a variable `v` of type `char**&`. But actually I need to convert it into `char*&` type. How should I do the conversion?

```
static char*& GetValue(char**& _v)
{
    static char* _vv;
    _vv = (char*)_v; //TODO: remove static
    return _vv;;
}
```

Comment: this really depends on the content of v etc. And is this some homework? because this looks like some reading concerning c and pointer is needed. Also you should tag this code C and not C++

Comment: @Hayt This **is** C++.  There are no references in C.

Comment: But is so ugly that it looks like C

Comment: Hey I didn't say it was pretty, just that it was C++ ;)  @OP how are you calling this function?

Comment: `static char*& GetValue(char**& _v)
{  return *_v; }` why wouldn't that work since variables scope are the same (in the caller)

Comment: @NathanOliver My bad. yeah I forgot about references being c++ with all the other pointer stuff there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example (I defined the `char*` as a type to see it more clearly):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef char * T;
static T & GetValue(T *& _v) { return *_v; }

    int main()
    {
      T s = nullptr;  // NULL if not C++ v11
      T *v = &s;
      T &vr = GetValue(v);
     cout << (void*)&vr << " " << (void*)&s << endl;

     return 0;

    }
```

`v` is safe in `main` scope. `GetValue` takes its reference then returns pointed value as a reference, with upper scope (not a temporary, I get no warning "returning reference to temporary" as opposed to if I return `T()`)

As further proof, running this code gives me both references equal:

```
0x28fea8 0x28fea8
```

any flaw in this reasoning/test?